# Display image grid using img tag

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have four square images with same width and height(may be 500*500) and I wanted to form the following grid with them using bootstrap grid.

[image]

And my html looks like below (run below snippet and see in fullscreen),

```css
.p0 {
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-sm-6 p0">
    <img src="https://nssdc.gsfc.nasa.gov/image/planetary/venus/gal_venus_37218.jpg" class="img-responsive">
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12 p0">
        <img src="http://www.gemini.edu/images/pio/press_release/2012/pr2012-8/fig1.jpg" class="img-responsive">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6 p0">
        <img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/7f/7f/53/7f7f536655a69664e130c797e359d27d--flowers-for-you-blue-flowers.jpg" class="img-responsive">
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6 p0">
        <img src="https://artstor.files.wordpress.com/2017/02/mma_fragmentary_head_ofa_queen2.png?w=500&h=500" class="img-responsive">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

without using background images and stretches on the images how can I achieve and get the above result.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you have a square image and you want to display it as a rectangle without stretching, you obviously have some work to do in said image first.

Comment: This doesn't look feasible just based on your diagram. Image #2 is not square.

Comment: float can basicly do the job, then resetting height and width on img will sort them out . Finally object-fit can be used to avoid stretching . https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WELeZo If you want to use boostrap, sizing img + eventually  object-fit should allow you to do what you look for https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gxZOOw

Comment: Thanks @G-Cyr got your point and solved my issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solved my problem and got my desired output with out stretching any image.

Here I set second image parent `position:relative` and `padding-top:50%`, then for the image `position:absolute` and `top:0`. It gives exactly what am looking for.

Thank you all for your support.

```css
.p0 {
  padding: 0 !important;
}

.half-img-container {
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 50% !important;
}

.half-img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-xs-6 p0">
    <img src="https://nssdc.gsfc.nasa.gov/image/planetary/venus/gal_venus_37218.jpg" class="img-responsive">
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-6">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 half-img-container p0">
        <img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/7f/7f/53/7f7f536655a69664e130c797e359d27d--flowers-for-you-blue-flowers.jpg" class="img-responsive half-img">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-6 p0">
        <img src="http://www.gemini.edu/images/pio/press_release/2012/pr2012-8/fig1.jpg" class="img-responsive">
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6 p0">
        <img src="https://artstor.files.wordpress.com/2017/02/mma_fragmentary_head_ofa_queen2.png?w=500&h=500" class="img-responsive">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use padding and margin for placement, for the picture on the left side (the big one) You can use `float: left;` I advice to use bootstrap. Much easier. You can also use for you divs: `max-width:'size what you want' and max-height:'size what you want`.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.p0 {
  padding: 0 !important;
}
.secondImg img {
  max-height: 164px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-6 p0">
    <img src="https://nssdc.gsfc.nasa.gov/image/planetary/venus/gal_venus_37218.jpg" class="img-responsive">
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-6">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 p0 secondImg">
        <img src="http://www.gemini.edu/images/pio/press_release/2012/pr2012-8/fig1.jpg" class="img-responsive">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-6 p0">
        <img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/7f/7f/53/7f7f536655a69664e130c797e359d27d--flowers-for-you-blue-flowers.jpg" class="img-responsive">
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6 p0">
        <img src="https://artstor.files.wordpress.com/2017/02/mma_fragmentary_head_ofa_queen2.png?w=500&h=500" class="img-responsive">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Image stretches!

Answer (score 0):

same ratio images on different size will cause some stretch. is below snippet is what you want ?

```css
.noPadd{
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
}
.p0 {
  padding-left: 0 !important;
  padding-right: 0 !important;
}
.left.one.large img{
height: 220px;
width: 100%;
}
.right.one img{
height: 110px;
width: 100%;
}
.right.two img{
height: 110px;
width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-xs-6 p0 left one large">
    <img src="https://nssdc.gsfc.nasa.gov/image/planetary/venus/gal_venus_37218.jpg" class="img-responsive">
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 noPadd">
    <div class="row right one">
      <div class="col-xs-12 p0">
        <img src="http://www.gemini.edu/images/pio/press_release/2012/pr2012-8/fig1.jpg" class="img-responsive">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row right two">
      <div class="col-xs-6 p0">
        <img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/7f/7f/53/7f7f536655a69664e130c797e359d27d--flowers-for-you-blue-flowers.jpg" class="img-responsive">
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6 p0">
        <img src="https://artstor.files.wordpress.com/2017/02/mma_fragmentary_head_ofa_queen2.png?w=500&h=500" class="img-responsive">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```